# while loop in Java returns both congratulations and sorry messages

Tags: java

I've been searching this for hours and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. This is my third program in Java and I am lost on an assignment. I have to modify the code to ask the user for a color, then ask them again and again until they guess “red” OR they have run out of guesses. They get 4 tries. I have to give them the feedback of "You guessed correctly in x number of tries" or "You ran out of tries. To get full credit, I need to use at most one loop and one condition. The original code uses a while to compare the color and gave unlimited guesses without counting.

This is what I have so far, and it does compile. However, if the answer isn't right the first time, it gives me both the congratulations and the sorry message. How do I fix that without using another loop?

```
/*************************************************************************
 *  Compilation:  javac JavaLa2.java
 *  Execution:    java JavaLab3
 *  Mary Ross
 *  Date: April 12, 2011
 *
 *  % java JavaLab3
 * This program will ask the user for a color. It will ask until they guess “red” OR they have run out of guesses. 
 * They have four guesses.
 * Example:
 * What is your name? Jordan
 * What color do you guess? White
 * let’s try again: What color do you guess? red
 * “Congratulations! You guessed the correct color in 2 tries.”
 * 
 * NOTE: I have put a lot of comments to guide you in the code.
 *************************************************************************/

import java.io.*;

public class JavaLab3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      // first we define our input streams.
      InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);   

      String sName ;
      String sColor;
      Integer numGuesses = 0;
      // we catch exceptions if some are thrown.
      try {
            System.out.println("what is your name?");
            sName = reader.readLine();  

            // then we will ask for the color
            System.out.println("What color do you guess?");
            sColor = reader.readLine();
            numGuesses = numGuesses +1;
            // at this point we have primed the condition for the while loop

            while (sColor.compareToIgnoreCase("red") != 0 && numGuesses < 4)  { 


                   System.out.println("You have guessed " + numGuesses + " times. You get four guesses.");
                   System.out.println("Let’s try again: What color do you guess?");
                   sColor = reader.readLine();
                   numGuesses = numGuesses + 1;

            System.out.println("Sorry, "  + sName + " you have exceeded your alloted guesses. The color is red.");


            }
           System.out.println("Congratulations! " + sName + " You correctly guessed Red in " + numGuesses + " tries.");
      } catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error reading from user");
       }

    }

}
```

Run with correct answer:

```
> what is your name?
 Mary
What color do you guess?
 red
Congratulations! Mary You correctly guessed Red in 1 tries.
```

Run with 1 wrong answer and the correct answer:

```
what is your name?
 Mary
What color do you guess?
 white
You have guessed 1 times. You get four guesses.
Let’s try again: What color do you guess?
 red
Sorry, Mary you have exceeded your alloted guesses. The color is red.
Congratulations! Mary You correctly guessed Red in 2 tries.
```

Comment: Autoformat your code, then see if you can spot the error.

Comment: downvoter - this is about as clear and well written as questions go, giving also the runnable code, so what's the reason for downvoting?

Comment: According to the comments in the code you have been working with this assignment for almost two years!!! But I agree with @eis. It is a well written question.

Comment: I didn't change the comments all of the way yet, they are the comments by my teacher on the original that we have to use as our base.

Answer (score 1):

Hey how do you know if your loop exited because the color is red or because the attempts are exhausted... You need to put that check. your sysout

System.out.println("Sorry, "  + sName + " you have exceeded your alloted guesses. The color is red.");

needs to be out of while loop and in an if condition immediately after while loop checking if attempts are exhausted.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the *sorry* message inside the *while* loop. So that will be printed everytime the loop runs. You need to move it outside. Also, your messages should be printed based on some condition.

You need to modify your `while` loop as:

```
while (sColor.compareToIgnoreCase("red") != 0 && numGuesses < 4)  { 

    System.out.println("You have guessed " + numGuesses + " times. You get four guesses.");
    System.out.println("Let’s try again: What color do you guess?");
    sColor = reader.readLine();

    // For incorrect guess, increase the `numGuesses`, and continue the loop
    numGuesses = numGuesses + 1;

}
if (numGuesses == 4) {
    // While loop breaks because of 2nd condition, Then print "Sorry"
    System.out.println("Sorry, "  + sName + " you have exceeded your alloted guesses. The color is red.");
} else {
    // 1st condition is satisfied. Correct color is guessed.
    System.out.println("Congratulations! " + sName + " You correctly guessed Red in " + numGuesses + " tries.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have exactly this behavior in your code:

```
while (sColor.compareToIgnoreCase("red") != 0 && numGuesses < 4)  { 


                   System.out.println("You have guessed " + numGuesses + " times. You get four guesses.");
                   System.out.println("Let’s try again: What color do you guess?");
                   sColor = reader.readLine();
                   numGuesses = numGuesses + 1;

            System.out.println("Sorry, "  + sName + " you have exceeded your alloted guesses. The color is red.");


            }
           System.out.println("Congratulations! " + sName + " You correctly guessed Red in " + numGuesses + " tries.");
```

"Congratulations" message is **always** printed after your `while` loop.

You need something like this **outside** of your loop::

```
if (numGuesses < 4)  {
    System.out.println("Congratulations! " + sName + " You correctly guessed Red in " + numGuesses + " tries.");
} else {
    System.out.println("Sorry, "  + sName + " you have exceeded your allotted guesses. The color is red.");
}
```

Comment: doesn't that make it two loops? Or is the if part of the while loop? That's whaere I am confused the most.

Comment: @Mary Ross - 
Well, actually **both** `println()` should be **outside** the loop.  I have revised my answer. Actually, **Rohit Jain** already provided such answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following:

```
        System.out.println("What color do you guess?");
        boolean isCorrectGuess = false; 
        if(sColor.compareToIgnoreCase("red") == 0) {
            isCorrectGuess  = true;
        }
        sColor = reader.readLine();
        numGuesses = numGuesses +1;
        // at this point we have primed the condition for the while loop

        while (!isCorrectGuess && numGuesses < 4)  { 


               System.out.println("You have guessed " + numGuesses + " times. You get four guesses.");
               System.out.println("Let’s try again: What color do you guess?");
               sColor = reader.readLine();
               numGuesses = numGuesses + 1;
               if(sColor.compareToIgnoreCase("red") == 0) {
                  isCorrectGuess  = true;
               }
        }
        if(!isCorrectGuess)
            System.out.println("Sorry, "  + sName + " you have exceeded your alloted guesses. The color is red.");
        else
             System.out.println("Congratulations! " + sName + " You correctly guessed Red in " + numGuesses + " tries.")
        }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is not all one loop, but other than thay, I like it.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you have not done any kind of condition check, in you Congrats SOP, so as soon as while loop ends, it moves to this SOP. You need to mention a condition which will provide some kind of control flow for the same. I guess something similar to this.

```
        if (sColor.compareToIgnoreCase("red")== 0 && numGuesses < 4) {
           System.out.println("Congratulations! " + sName + " You correctly guessed Red in " + numGuesses + " tries.");
        }
```

Few tips:

Instead of using **compareToIgnoreCase** you can switch to **equalsIgnoreCase**

What I have used in if condition, you can also do with a boolean flag, toggle it to true once you get the correct input.

Comment: I have to use compareToIgnoreCase to not  equal to 0 for the while it is in the teacher's original. But you think that I should use is equal to in the test?

Answer (score 0):

Some logic framing problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
        // first we define our input streams.
        InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);

        String sName;
        String sColor;
        Integer numGuesses = 0;
        // we catch exceptions if some are thrown.
        try {
            System.out.println("what is your name?");
            sName = reader.readLine();

            // then we will ask for the color
//            System.out.println("What color do you guess?");
//            sColor = reader.readLine();
//            numGuesses = numGuesses + 1;
            // at this point we have primed the condition for the while loop

            while (numGuesses < 4) {
                System.out.println("What color do you guess?");
                sColor = reader.readLine();
                numGuesses = numGuesses + 1;
                if (sColor.compareToIgnoreCase("red") != 0) {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, " + sName + " you have exceeded your alloted guesses. The color is red.");

                    System.out.println("You have guessed " + numGuesses + " times. You get four guesses.");
//                    System.out.println("Let’s try again: What color do you guess?");

//                    sColor = reader.readLine();
//                    numGuesses = numGuesses + 1;

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Congratulations! " + sName + " You correctly guessed Red in " + numGuesses + " tries.");
                    break;
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error reading from user");
        }

    }
```

**Output1:**

```
what is your name?
Kiran
What color do you guess?
a
Sorry, Kiran you have exceeded your alloted guesses. The color is red.
You have guessed 1 times. You get four guesses.
What color do you guess?
a
Sorry, Kiran you have exceeded your alloted guesses. The color is red.
You have guessed 2 times. You get four guesses.
What color do you guess?
a
Sorry, Kiran you have exceeded your alloted guesses. The color is red.
You have guessed 3 times. You get four guesses.
What color do you guess?
a
Sorry, Kiran you have exceeded your alloted guesses. The color is red.
You have guessed 4 times. You get four guesses.
```

**output2**:

```
what is your name?
Kiran
What color do you guess?
Pink
Sorry, Kiran you have exceeded your alloted guesses. The color is red.
You have guessed 1 times. You get four guesses.
What color do you guess?
red
Congratulations! Kiran You correctly guessed Red in 2 tries.
```

Comment: The first part that you commented was written by our teacher to build on and has to be in the program. I will look at the 2xn chunk more closely

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: when the first time people guess wrong and able to guess again, even people guess right at this time, the "Sorry" output message is still in this while loop. Which means during second try, people guess right, the code will execute the "sorry" print and end the while loop to execute the "Congratulations" out print.